# Custom object as value for Mapper output

Tags: hadoop

I have object have constructed as following:

```
Class ObjExample {
     String s;
     Object[] objArray; // element in this array can be primitive type or array of primitive type.
}
```

I know that to using it as output type for mapper or reducer, we have to implement  WritableComparable for it.

But I really get confused how to write readFields(), write(), compareTo() for this kind of class?

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap field `s` in `Text` and `objArray` in `ArrayWritable`. Each element of the `objArray` would be an array (also `ArrayWritable`) of primitives. Here is possible implementation:

```
public static final class ObjExample implements WritableComparable<ObjExample> {
    public final Text s = new Text(); // wrapped String
    public final ArrayOfArrays objArray = new ArrayOfArrays();

    @Override
    public int compareTo(ObjExample o) {
        // your logic here, example:
        return s.compareTo(o.s);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(DataOutput dataOutput) throws IOException {
        s.write(dataOutput);
        objArray.write(dataOutput);
    }

    @Override
    public void readFields(DataInput dataInput) throws IOException {
        s.readFields(dataInput);
        objArray.readFields(dataInput);
    }

    // set size of the objArray
    public void setSize(int n) {
        objArray.set(new IntArray[n]);
    }

    // set i-th element of the objArray to an array of elements
    public void setElement(int i, IntWritable... elements) {
        IntArray subArr = new IntArray();
        subArr.set(elements);
        objArray.get()[i] = subArr;
    }
}
```

You will need two more classes to make it work:

```
// array of primitives
public static final class IntArray extends ArrayWritable {
    public IntArray() {
        // you can specify any other primitive wrapper (DoubleWritable, Text, ...)
        super(IntWritable.class);
    }
}

// array of arrays
public static final class ArrayOfArrays extends ArrayWritable {
    public ArrayOfArrays() {
        super(IntArray.class);
    }
}
```

Example of construction of the object:

```
ObjExample o = new ObjExample();
o.s.set("hello");
o.setSize(2);
o.setElement(0, new IntWritable(0)); // single primitive
o.setElement(1, new IntWritable(1), new IntWritable(2)); // array of primitives
```

Comment: Thanks for your great support Alexei. But I still have one question.

Is there anyway for us to write or read directly String and Object array using DataInput or DataOutput  without wrapping to Hadoop type like above.

If yes, how is its performance. I mean is it better or worst if compare with implementation above?

Comment: @ndk076 You can write your own serialization/deserialization mechanism, but the default hadoop's serialization is good enough. For example `Text` is stored as its length and the array of bytes. You can try to improve it with using of some fast compression codec, but i can't say if it worth your effort.